# Sending via the Quote

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have the following custom code that I am placing on the Opportunity object.  I want to click this custom Send With DocuSign button and have it load the most recent's quote's attachments. My code is unfortunately not working.  Is there something I am missing and need to add?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
var rc = GetRelContentIDs("{!Opportunity.Id}");
var RQD = DSGetPageIDFromHref();
var LA = 1;
window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&RQD="+RQD+"&LA="+LA+"&RC="+rc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a specific error message?

The second example from the documentation works for me:

https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSignForSalesforceReleaseNotesv4.1.17.pdf#page=2

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 

var sourceId = DSGetPageIDFromHref(); 
var rc = GetRelContentIDs(sourceId); 
var LA = 1; 
window.location.href = 
"/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID="+sourceId+"&rc=
"+rc+"&RQD=" + sourceId+"&LA="+LA;
```

I believe the issue you are running into is when you are adding the merge fields for the SourceID and RC parameter.

Comment: How would I be able to send via the Opportunity and only pull the Quote attachments?  Using the code above, it will pull the Opportunity attachments.  Would I just need to change the SourceId in the RC parameter?

Comment: Have you tried it yet? I simply used the example within the documentation and works perfect. I don't know the design behind the logic, but I'm assuming it's the Related Content parameter controls the attachment of the child object. In this case, the "Quote".

Comment: Do you get a specific error message or does the QuotePDF just never get attached to the envelope?

Comment: Are you attempting to attach the most recent "**Quote PDF**"? Or the most recent document from "**Notes and Attachments**"? The example above is specific to "**Quote PDFs**".

Comment: That was it then.  I was assuming that it would pull the notes and attachments.  That makes sense now.  Thanks!